# NN training with Matlab: train() function output is not consistent with MSE error

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I've just started using Matlab's toolbox for simple Neural Nets training.
My Matlab version is 2019a.
However, there is one thing that confuses me. Consider this code:

```
 Nsamples=1000;
 NoiseMag=0.2;
 rx=linspace(-1,1,Nsamples);
 ry = rx + NoiseMag*randn(size(rx));

 net=feedforwardnet(50);
 [net,tr]=train(net,rx,ry);
```

This piece of code trains feedforward NN with a single hidden layer on noisy samples `(rx,ry)`. The thing that I am confused about is that network's training error output by `tr.perf` is not consistent with `mse(net,rx(tr.trainInd),ry(tr.trainInd))`:

```
  tr.perf   %output: [9.7205    0.0419    0.0370    0.0364    0.0361    0.0358    0.0356    0.0355    0.0355    0.0354]
 mse(net,rx(tr.trainInd),ry(tr.trainInd)) . %Output 0.0401
```

Explanation: `tr.perf` outputs training error for each iteration (or epoch). The next command `mse(net,rx(tr.trainInd),ry(tr.trainInd))` outputs training error for the current (optimal) neural network parameters.

Since `tr.best_epoch` is `3`, the third element of `tr.perf` should be exactly equal to `mse(net,rx(tr.trainInd),ry(tr.trainInd))`, but it is not.

Any idea why? 
I also observe the same inconsistency when compare validation and test errors.
If you compile these examples, your output will be slightly different because of randomness in samples and initial weights of NN.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not read the documentation of `mse` function carefully.

```
  mse(net,targets,outputs,errorWeights,...parameters...) calculates a
network performance given targets, outputs, error weights and parameters
as the mean of squared errors.
```

Therefore, the second parameter has to be the target, and the third - network outcomes. After fixing the code, the output becomes consistent. The function that I was looking for - that simply calculates mean squared error of two vectors - is called `immse`

```
 mse(net,ry(tr.trainInd),net(rx(tr.trainInd))) % output 0.0334
 tr.perf(tr.best_epoch+1) % output 0.0334
 immse(net(rx(tr.trainInd)),ry(tr.trainInd)) % output 0.0334
```